# Google Map Api iPhone

Tags: iphone

I am using search place API in my application ,its working fine.
But in Place API , am passing parameters map center coordinates and radius with API KEY. 
its giving response. But,if i want to search any location whether its  region visible in screen or not as in in-built map application . How should i go for this?is there any different query or API for achieving it ?

Right now , am using below query.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=50000&types=&name=%@&sensor=false&key=aaaaaaaaaa",mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude,mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude,searchPlace.text]];
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connect;
connect =  [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",[searchPlace.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

you can try this...  may be it's help you...